# Как сделать закрытие окна QMainWindow по кнопке на QDockWidget?

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5

Необходимо добавить закрытие основного окна по кнопке QPushButton. Никак не могу найти информацию как это сделать. Привожу часть своего кода

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://yandex.ru"))

        self.browser.urlChanged.connect(self.update_urlbar)
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.update_title)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

        self.status = QStatusBar()
        self.setStatusBar(self.status)

## QDockWidget ##
        self.docked = QDockWidget("Виджет", self)
        self.addDockWidget(Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.docked)
        self.dockedWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.docked.setWidget(self.dockedWidget)
        self.dockedWidget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.dockedWidget.layout().addWidget(QPushButton('Завершить работу'))
```

Кнопка создана на панели, но как добавить чтобы по нажатию закрывалось окно? Стандартный крестик отключил, именно такой вариант необходим. Помогите кто сможет)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного измените ваш код на следующий:

```
button = QPushButton(('Завершить работу'))

# Соединяем клик по кнопке со слотом закрытия главного окна
# Здесь self это объект вашего окна MainWindow 
button.clicked.connect(self.close)

self.dockedWidget.layout().addWidget(button)
```